# Balancing a BST with weights

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree, recursive-datastructures, tree-balancing

I'm building a recursive Java method to balance a binary search tree (using ints, but designed generic) using weights in each node. For my purpose, the weight of a node is defined as the number of children + 1.

```
  2
/   \
1   3

The weight of the root is 3, and the weight of both leaves is 1.
```

At the end of the balancing, the value at any node should be the median of the values at all nodes in the subtree rooted at that node.

Here is my code:

```
public void weightBalance (BinarySearchTree<AnyType> t) {

    // Base case
    if (t.getRoot().left == null && t.getRoot().right == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Get median of tree
    AnyType median = t.getMedian();

    // Create new BST with median as root
    BinarySearchTree<AnyType> newTree = new BinarySearchTree<AnyType>();
    newTree.insert(median);

    // Insert all values except median into new BST
    ArrayList<AnyType> stack = new ArrayList<AnyType>();
    inorderTraverse(t.getRoot(), stack);
    Iterator<AnyType> itr = stack.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        AnyType temp = itr.next();
        if (temp != median) {  // Comparing values or reference?
            newTree.insert(temp);
        }
    }

    // Replace old BST with new BST
    t = newTree;  // t is a copy of the reference, is this the problem?

    // Recurse through children
    // Tree constructor for reference:
    // public BinarySearchTree (BinaryNode<AnyType> t) {
    //  root = t;
    // }

    if (t.getRoot().left != null) {
        weightBalance(new BinarySearchTree(t.getRoot().left));
    }
    if (t.getRoot().right != null) {
        weightBalance(new BinarySearchTree(t.getRoot().right));
    }
}
```

I'm trying to modify the tree in place without returning anything, but the code does not change the tree. I *know* I'm messing by passing by reference and passing by value somewhere, but I can't figure out where - can anyone help out? I've spent a few hours debugging but I get really confused when debugging recursion.

Comment: Have a look at a related question on AVL trees, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771827/implementing-an-avl-tree-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Balancing algorithms are fairly common and well documented, e.g. TreeMap is a BST and you can see it source.  I have never seen it use a copy of data, I doubt you need to create a stack or build a new tree just to balance it.

The normal behaviour is to rotate nodes, left or right, or a more complex combination of both.  This reduces the work involved and doesn't create an garbage.